# Decoding string n[Am[b]]

Tags: string

There are strings in that view:

```
2[a]2[ab]
3[a]2[r2[t]]
a2[aa3[b]]
```

Digits means count of repeat string inside brackets. So decoding string will be:

```
aaabab
aaarttrtt
aaabbbaabbb
```

I need an algorithm of decoding string, preferable on Java

Comment: Please add more details to your question, there is not even a context of what you are referring to

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution with recursion. Just take symbol by symbol, and as soon as we meet the digit - it means begin of packed string. Call method unpacked, where inside call unpacked again on next digit appeareance.